# Deriving algorithm efficiency on a linear search

Tags: python, algorithm

For a simple linear search on an unsorted list my textbook says the following:

To determine the average case, you add the number of iterations required to find the target at each possible position and divide the sum by n. Thus, the algorithm performs (n + n - 1 + n -2 + ... + 1)/n, or (n + 1)/2 iterations.

The code example he uses is this:

```
def sequentialSearch(target, lyst):
    """Returns the position of the target item if found, or -1 otherwise."""
    position = 0
    while position < len(lyst):
        if target == lyst[position]:
            return position
        position += 1
    return False
```

I'm having trouble understanding how he is deriving (n + 1)/2 from the above?

Comment: It is just O(n ) not n(n+1)/2 . n(n+1)/2 is just the sum of all the numbers from 1 to n

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm not reading the code right, or not understanding the question either, but I think this algorithm runs in `O(n)` because it iterates through the list at most checking all the elements ONCE, making the total amount of checks be `n-1` checks.

Comment: Do you want to know why the algorithm performs `(n + n - 1 + n -2 + ... + 1)/n` iterations on the average, or why `(n + n - 1 + n -2 + ... + 1)/n == (n+1)/2`?

Comment: @AkshayHazari the queation has nothing to do with the big-O notation. It asks "how many iterations", not "how many iterations up to a constant factor".

Comment: @n.m. both really, but more the second question.

Comment: @n.m. Oh. I just missed the avg case part. Its Sunday morning here.

Comment: I don't think you can pass CS101 without knowing how to sum up an arithmetic sequence, so you need to brush up your high school algebra or whatever. As for the first question, the searched-for item can be at position 1 or 2 or ... or n-1 or n, to find the average you add them all up and divide by the number of cases.

Comment: @flybonzai . Nothing to worry about if you don't understand something. Slow learners eventually turn out to be brighter many times provided there is perseverance

Comment: Thanks:)  I'm teaching myself computer science, so I don't have the background in math some programmers have already.

Comment: Nothing wrong with starting from a blank page but you will need to acquire some math background one way or another. Specifically on the sum of the arithmetic progression, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: It was Aryabhatta who came up with arithmetic progression . Even millennium later discoveries in maths and astronomy were first discovered by him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a list to get to the possible target you might take `n,n-1,...2,1` attempts to find it. So if you want to find avg case . It will simply be an addition of them all and divided by n. `(n+n-1+...+2+1)/n` . We know that `(n+n-1+...+2+1) = n(n+1)/2` . So we get answer as `n(n+1)/2*n` which is `(n+1)/2` as the avg case.

e.g. for linear search

```
 lyst = [4,5,2,1,6]
 possibilities of targets = 4 or 5 or 2 or 1 or 6
 target = 4
 attemps reqd = 1 as found in first attempt i.e first location
 lyst = [4,5,2,1,6]
 target = 5
 attemps reqd = 2 as found in second attempt i.e second location
 lyst = [4,5,2,1,6]
 target = 2
 attemps reqd = 3 as found in third attempt i.e third location
 lyst = [4,5,2,1,6]
 target = 1
 attemps reqd = 4 as found in fourth attempt i.e fourth location
 lyst = [4,5,2,1,6]
 target = 6
 attemps reqd = 5 as found in fifth attempt i.e fifth location

 sum of all attempts reqired = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 
 same as n(n+1)/2 = 5(5+1)/2 = 5*3 = 15

 avg case = (1+2+3+4+5)/n = 15/5 = 3
 same as n(n+1)/2*n = 5(6)/2*5 = (n+1)/2 = 6/2 = 3
```

Avg means sum of all elements divided by number of elements.

Comment: Isn't (n+1)/2 the same as O(logn)?

Comment: No that is binary search which is done on a sorted list. It is dividing the list by two and check if it  is small or big if not then you found the target else the list to check is either left half or right. (n+1)/2 is the avg case, nothing to do with bigO